# Angular HTTP get type check with nested interfaces

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-httpclient

I was wondering if HttpClient get can type check nested interfaces.

For example I use GitHub API. If you check this request's:
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=angular
response you will see that the actual findings are in an array (*'items'*).

So I want to extract the *items* array and also want to store the *total_count*.

I came up with this interface:

```ts
export interface Repository {
    name: string;
    full_name: string;
    size: string;
    forks_count: string;
    created_at: string;
    url: string;
    description: string;
    stargazers_count: string;
    open_issues_count: string;
}
```

and...

```ts
import { Repository } from "./repository.model";

export interface ReposirotySearchResponse {
    items: Repository[];
    total_count: number;
}
```

Based on *ReposirotySearchResponse* I want to extract the mentioned response with this:

```ts
return this._http.get<ReposirotySearchResponse>('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=angular');
```

But unfortunately angular doesn't resolve the response with the given type.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Are you getting any exception/error?

Comment: get returns the unparsed json response

Comment: Please check import statement it should be import { Repository } from './repository';

Comment: The name of the file is repository.model.ts, that is why it is imported like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duncan, http.get give you a complete response, so you must "map" the response if you want to get other response

```
return this._http.get<ReposirotySearchResponse>('https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=angular')
    .map((result:any)=>{
      console.log(result); //<--there the complete response
        return{
          total_count:result.total_count,
          items:result.items.map((item:any)=>{
            return {
              name: item.name,
              full_name: item.full_name,
              size: item.size,
              forks_count: item.forks_count,
              created_at: item.created_at,
              url: item.url,
              description: item.description,
              stargazers_count: item.stargazers_count,
              open_issues_count: item.open_issues_count
            }
          })
        }
      })
```

when you subscribe you receive only the fiels you want

Comment: @Eliseo - Good one to get only mapped fields instead of all.